# How to split lines from bufferedReader into words

Tags: java, split, bufferedreader

I need help to create code that splits lines of codes and then it can make some spelling check.

```
  public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
    Stem myStem = new Stem();

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\lamrh\\IdeaProjects\\untitled1\\src\\bigON\\data.txt")));

    //String currentWord = String.valueOf(bufferedReader.readLine());
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(bufferedReader.readLine());
    //byte[] data = new byte [currentWord.length()];
    String[] splitLines;
    //splitLines = splitLines.split(" ");


    String line;
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) !=null  ){
        //splitLines = line.split(" ");
        String currentWord1 = formatWordGhizou ( line);
        System.out.println(""+ line+""+ ":"+ currentWord1);

    }
    bufferedReader.close();


}
```

Where the results show me this:

```
سْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ:سماللهالرحمنالرحيم
```

`سْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ:سماللهالرحمنالرحيم
ِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ:سماللهالرحمنالرحيم
ِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ:سماللهالرحمنالرحيم
ِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ:سماللهالرحمنالرحيم
ِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ:سماللهالرحمنالرحيم
ِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ:سماللهالرحمنالرحيم
ِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ:سماللهالرحمنالرحيم`  ِ

Where it should look like word by word not a line of words.
 any help 
Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide the source of the function "formatWordGhizou()"?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: The question was is there any way to split lines that have been read by bufferedreader into words

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop try concatenating the line strings into lines, splitting lines using regex to populate String array splitLines and then iterating through array splitLines to send elements to standard output as follows ([adapted from helpful tutorial at this link](http://javadevnotes.com/java-string-split-space-or-whitespace-examples))

```
String lines="";

while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) !=null  ){

   lines = lines  + line;  

}

String[] splitLines = lines.split("\\s+");

for (String words: splitLines) {

     System.out.println(words);

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// format the word by removing any punctuation, diacritics and non-letter charracters
private static String formatWordGhizou ( String currentWord )
{
    StringBuffer modifiedWord = new StringBuffer ( );


    // remove any diacritics (short vowels)
    if ( removeDiacritics( currentWord, modifiedWord ) )
    {
        currentWord = modifiedWord.toString ( );
    }

    // remove any punctuation from the word
    if ( removePunctuation( currentWord, modifiedWord ) )
    {
        currentWord = modifiedWord.toString ( ) ;
    }

    // there could also be characters that aren't letters which should be removed
    if ( removeNonLetter ( currentWord, modifiedWord ) )
    {
        currentWord = modifiedWord.toString ( );
    }

    // check for stopwords
    if( !checkStrangeWords ( currentWord ) )
        // check for stopwords
        if( !checkStopwords ( currentWord ) )
            currentWord = stemWord ( currentWord );

    return currentWord;
}

//-----------------
```